# Zebra connection android

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

Does anyone know if BT_MULTI works on Zebra? I'm using ZebraConnection class in my android application and connection with BT:printerAddress as parameter works but with BT_MULTI:printerAddress throws "Invalid connection type".

I'm trying to use BT_MULTI to connect multiple printers in one time, but if you have other ideas of how I can do that I'll be happy to hear them.

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
Connection connection;
        try {

            connection= ConnectionBuilder.build(getConnectionStringForSdk(printerBTAddress));
            connection.open();
            ZebraPrinter printerdemo = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);

        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection could not be opened"+e);
        } catch (ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to create printer"+e);
        }

  private String getConnectionStringForSdk(String btAddress) {
    String selectedPrefix="BT_MULTI:";
    final String finalConnectionString = selectedPrefix + btAddress;
    return finalConnectionString;
}
```